# android webview customview onHideCustomView error

Tags: android, webview

Hi I'm making an webview app

I making a webview and i want to supprot fullscreen video

So i make customview but it have error

error come from onHideCustomView

How can i fix this error?

LogCat

```
11-12 21:25:23.340    5340-5340/com.bayabro.bayabro E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
        at android.view.ViewGroup.addViewInner(ViewGroup.java:3620)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3491)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3467)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:332)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:322)
        at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1944)
        at com.bayabro.bayabro.MyActivity$MyWebChromeClient.onHideCustomView(MyActivity.java:151)
        at com.bayabro.bayabro.MyActivity.onKeyDown(MyActivity.java:174)
        at android.view.KeyEvent.dispatch(KeyEvent.java:2705)
        at android.app.Activity.dispatchKeyEvent(Activity.java:2431)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2028)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverKeyEventPostIme(ViewRootImpl.java:3852)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleImeFinishedEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3800)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewRootHandler.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2935)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4921)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1038)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:805)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

my app full code

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
WebView myWebView;
private MyWebChromeClient mWebChromeClient = null;
private View mCustomView;
private RelativeLayout mContentView;
private FrameLayout mCustomViewContainer;
private WebChromeClient.CustomViewCallback mCustomViewCallback;
FrameLayout.LayoutParams LayoutParameters = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
        FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
private ValueCallback<Uri> mUploadMessage;
private final static int FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE=1;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);
    myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
    myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    myWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
    myWebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    myWebView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
    myWebView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
    myWebView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
    myWebView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    myWebView.getSettings().setDefaultTextEncodingName("EUR-KR");
    myWebView.loadDataWithBaseURL(null,"","text/html","utf-8",null);
    myWebView.getSettings().setGeolocationEnabled(true);
    myWebView.getSettings().setDatabaseEnabled(true);
    myWebView.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
    myWebView.getSettings().setAppCacheMaxSize(1024*1024*8);
    myWebView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    mWebChromeClient = new MyWebChromeClient();
    //mWebChromeClient = new WMWebChromeClient();
    myWebView.setWebChromeClient(mWebChromeClient);
    String databasePath = myWebView.getContext().getDir("databases",
            Context.MODE_PRIVATE).getPath();
    myWebView.getSettings().setDatabasePath(databasePath);
    myWebView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
    myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
    //mwebview.getSettings().setLayoutAlgorithm(WebSettings.LayoutAlgorithm.SINGLE_COLUMN);
    myWebView.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);
    myWebView.getSettings().setSupportMultipleWindows(true);
    myWebView.loadUrl("http://www.naver.com");
    myWebView.setWebChromeClient(new MyWebChromeClient());
    myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoadding(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
    });
}
private class MyWebChromeClient extends WebChromeClient {
    @Override
    public void onShowCustomView(View view, CustomViewCallback callback) {
        // if a view already exists then immediately terminate the new one
        if (mCustomView != null) {
            callback.onCustomViewHidden();
            return;
        }
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        mContentView = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.www);
        mContentView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        mCustomViewContainer = new FrameLayout(MyActivity.this);
        mCustomViewContainer.setLayoutParams(LayoutParameters);
        mCustomViewContainer.setBackgroundResource(android.R.color.black);
        view.setLayoutParams(LayoutParameters);
        mCustomViewContainer.addView(view);
        mCustomView = view;
        mCustomViewCallback = callback;
        mCustomViewContainer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        setContentView(mCustomViewContainer);
    }
    public void onBackPressed(){
        if(mCustomViewContainer!=null)
            mCustomViewCallback.onCustomViewHidden();

    }
    public void onHideCustomView() {
        if (mCustomView == null) {
            return;
        } else {
            getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN);
            mCustomView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            // Remove the custom view from its container.
            mCustomViewContainer.removeView(mCustomView);
            mCustomView = null;
            mCustomViewContainer.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            mCustomViewCallback.onCustomViewHidden();
            // Show the content view.
            mContentView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            setContentView(mContentView);
        }
    }
}
public void onPause(){
    super.onPause();
    myWebView.onPause();
}

public boolean onKeyDown(int key, KeyEvent event) {
    if (myWebView != null && mCustomViewContainer != null&&key == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
        if(mWebChromeClient == null){
            Toast.makeText(MyActivity.this,"hell",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        };
        mWebChromeClient.onHideCustomView();
        return true;
    }
    else if(myWebView!=null&&(key == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)&&myWebView.canGoBack()){
        myWebView.goBack();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(key, event);
}
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.my, menu);
    return true;
}
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```